# Ajax to get input textbox array and display the result to a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This is my display form

```
<form name='foodlist' action='checkout' method='POST'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Name</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Amount</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='foodname[]' size='10' class='foodname' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='price[]' size='2' class='price'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='qty[]' size='2' class='qty'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='amt[]'  size='2' class='amt'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='foodname[]' size='10' class='foodname' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='price[]' size='2' class='price'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='qty[]' size='2' class='qty'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='amt[]'  size='2' class='amt'/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I have AJAX jQuery to get input values.

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : "ajaxfood.php",
  data: $('[name="qty[]"]').serialize(),
  success : function(html) {
    alert (html);
  }
});
```

This is my php:

```
<?php
  $qtys = $_POST['qty'];
  echo json_encode($qtys);
?>
```

The above code is working perfectly and displaing the qty array.
But my problem is I want to get all the textboxes in my php. I tried to send the while form but it won't worked

```
data: $('form').serialize(),
```

1. What is the way to send the whole form data.
2. and how to get it php.
3. and how to put the result in a div.

My first question is very important for me.
please help

Comment: What do you mean by "won't worked"?

Comment: @JayBlanchard the 

data: $('form').serialize(),

 I write in place of 

 data: $('[name="qty[]"]').serialize(),
is not working

Comment: data: $('form input').serialize(),

Comment: @Robin I didn't get you, where to write the code, what is wrong in my code

Comment: @wishab it returns  "null"

Comment: it is sending variables. just need to work in your php. https://jsfiddle.net/qqvn1pc6/1/

Comment: When using $('form').serialize() for the data, in your PHP file, if you do "var_dump($_POST);" without quotes, do you see the other variables from your form?

Comment: @mark.hch yes all the variables are visible individually. Please tell me how to use var_dump.

Comment: Now after using var_dump I am getting result but like this
array(2) { ["qty"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" } }

and displays without echo , how to get different arrays and display the value only. not ver_dump result

@mark.hch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$('form').serializeArray()` for your AJAX data in your JS.
If you're on a new version of Chrome, you can use the console in your Dev Tools (F12) to view the output in a table with:

```
var formArray = $('form').serializeArray(); 
console.table(formArray);
```

If you see all the info in there, it should be available in your PHP `$_POST` variable for your server-side code. Use the same `var_dump()` call on the server to make sure it's there. - http://jsfiddle.net/rsrj07fn/

This will get the information to the server, and print it out on the server to make sure it's there. `var_dump()` is not for your finished product, just for debugging purposes to visually see what is assigned to server side variables (like `$_POST`). If you want to use just the string values of the data which made it to the server, you should be able to use, for example:

```
echo $_POST['foodname'][0];
echo $_POST['foodname'][1];

echo $_POST['price'][0];
echo $_POST['price'][1];
```

etc.

To put them all in one DIV:

```
echo "<div>";
   echo $_POST['foodname'][0]."<br>";
   echo $_POST['foodname'][1]."<br>";
   echo $_POST['price'][0]."<br>";
   echo $_POST['price'][1]."<br>";
   echo $_POST['qty'][0]."<br>";
   echo $_POST['qty'][1]."<br>";
   echo $_POST['amt'][0]."<br>";
   echo $_POST['amt'][1]."<br>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: but var_dump is automatically echo the whole array. including my formated result. how to stop var_dump to display

Comment: I wrote the code in this way
$a= sizeof($_POST['qty']);
for($i=0;$i<$a;$i++)
   { echo $_POST['qty'][$i]}